# Using filter in couchDB / PouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a design document in couchDB

```
{
  "_id": "_design/my_index_id",
  "_rev": "10-f1c6f1c088963f97e39093f0bd175da1",
  "views": {
    "onlyjobs": {
      "map": "function (doc) {if  (doc.type === 'load') {emit(doc.id);}}"
    }
  },
  "filters": {
    "myfilter": "function (doc, req) {return req.query.type === 'load'}"
  }
}
```

I want to sync the DB based on my filter (myfilter).

Here's how I do sync

```
  this.db
      .sync(this.remoteDB, {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        include_docs: true,
        filter: 'my_index_id/myfilter'
        query_params: { type: 'load' }

      })
```

But this gives 404 (Object Not Found) Error. When I use Views, they work correctly but I cant seem to use the filters properly.

Basically I want to leverage query params and use filter based on some logic. Can I do this with View?

Comment: In order to check if the filter is properly created could you launch this URL on your server? .../<your-db>/_changes?filter=my_index_id/myfilter&type=load

Comment: Yes, I got an results array which includes "seq" and "changes". It same number as the expected result. why isn't it syncing from PouchDB?

Comment: Then, the filter is correctly defined in your DB. Seems to be something in your client side. 404 is returned when the filter is not found in the database.

Comment: The filter is defined in your local database or the remote one?

Comment: Remote Database.